# how to group the elements in a list and display in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display list of items by grouping them based on their created date. Here is my controller code:

```
 $scope.itemList = function () {
      return  itemService.getList();      
};
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="date in itemDates = (itemList()| unique:dtTime)">
    <div id="itemDay" class="itemFont">{{getAbbrevatedDate(date.dtTime)}}</div>   
    <div ng-repeat="item in itemList()"">   
        <div ng-show="getAbbrevatedDate(date.dtTime) === getAbbrevatedDate(item.dtTime)" id="itemRow">    
            <div id="itemRowContent">               
                <div id="itemName" class="itemFont">{{item.name}}</div>
                <div id="itemDescription" class="itemFont">{{item.description}}</div>

            </div>           
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

The data in itemList are:

```
[{
    "name":"itemx001",
    "dtTime":"2016-01-13T10:17:31.279-05:00",
    "description":"this item delivered last week"
},
{
    "name":"itemx002",
    "dtTime":"2016-01-13T10:17:31.279-05:00",
    "description":"this item delivered yesterday"
},
{
    "name":"itemx003",
    "dtTime":"2016-01-12T10:17:31.279-05:00",
    "description":"this item delivered last month"
},
{
    "name":"itemx004",
    "dtTime":"2016-01-12T10:17:31.279-05:00",
    "description":"this item delivered last November"
}
{
    "name":"itemx005",
    "dtTime":"2016-01-12T10:17:31.279-05:00",
    "description":"this item delivered last October"
}]
```

getAbbrevatedDate() returns Today, Yesterday, Last week, etc.

I am getting the following output:

```
Today
itemx001
this item delivered last week
itemx002
this item delivered yesterday
Today
itemx001
this item delivered last week
itemx002
this item delivered yesterday
yesterday
itemx003
this item delivered last month
itemx004
this item delivered last November
itemx005
this item delivered last October
yesterday
itemx003
this item delivered last month
itemx004
this item delivered last November
itemx005
this item delivered last October
It is repeating the loop for each item. But I am trying to display like this
Today
itemx001
this item delivered last week
itemx002
this item delivered yesterday
yesterday
itemx003
this item delivered last month
itemx004
this item delivered last November
itemx005
this item delivered last October
```

How do I group these items by created date without repeating? I tried with unique but it did not work.

Comment: should dtTime be a string in the filter? i.e. `unique: 'dtTime'`

Comment: why do you have nested repeat of `itemList()` ? Take that out

Comment: yes it is string. and getAbbrevatedDate() takes dtTime as argument and returns abbrevated day.

Comment: I removed nested repeat but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise that you perform this transformation only one time, and as soon as you have the data available.

Trying to achieve this in the ng-repeat will be very expensive in terms of CPU because Angular will need to run all those functions everytime there is a `$scope.$digest`

An example of how you would do this [can be found in this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hci2VSQr9EusmgTyFQCm?p=preview).
Note that the example uses [lodash#groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy)

Answer (score 0):

the unique filter is not working correctly for you (also make sure to reference the ui.filter module from [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js)), here how it should be:

```
<div ng-repeat="date in itemList  | unique:'dtTime' ">
     {{ date.dtTime}}

     <div ng-repeat="item in itemList ">   
        <div ng-show="date.dtTime === item.dtTime" id="itemRow">    
            <div id="itemRowContent">               
                <div id="itemName" class="itemFont">{{item.name}}</div>
                <div id="itemDescription" class="itemFont">{{item.description}}</div>

            </div>           
        </div>      
    </div>
```

I did not use your method getAbbrevatedDate(), but you can use it!

Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3oRjZIdzZ3FdGqhLb77M?p=preview) link to see it

Comment: I tried this solution , when I applied unique filter for same date and different timestamps it is treating them different. for example, timestamps 2016-01-15T16:17:38.928-05:00,2016-01-15T15:15:30.928-05:00 it is not grouping. Is there a way to apply unique filter to date part of dtTime field?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to do this inside the AngularJS filter, but you can always create another method in your controller called getDates() that takes the dates from the itemList() and computes the unique sequence of dates using jQuery ($.unique) or underscore (_.uniq).